# Save button on profile picture module not working or module is getting stuck at "Uploading..." PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a module where a user can upload a profile picture. I want to do several things when a user uploads a picture to there profile, but I am trying to take it in steps, the first step being getting the picture saved and uploaded to the server. Right now, the user can select there picture just fine, after the user has chosen there picture, it gives a little notice that the picture is uploading. I don't know if something is supposed to show after uploading or if it is just supposed to go away (I joined a friend in getting this site done, the module was already here; I'm trying to get the functionality finished up and working).

This is what it looks like:
[image: Profile Picture Module]

I have noticed though, that if you click save nothing seems to happen. Like the save button is not set up correctly or something.

I suspect that the the issue of the pictures not being uploaded is either because of the "Uploading..." text or the save button not working. I have tried to debug by echoing out if $_FILES is getting the picture that I am trying to upload, but the module does not reload to allow me to see if $_FILES is getting anything (it's not making it to the if loop of what happens after the save button has been clicked.

Here is the code for the module itself:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
        <center>
            <h3>Edit Profile Picture</h3>
            <img src="images/default.png" name="aboutme" width="140" height="140" border="0" class="img-circle"></a></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>

        </center>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="cropimage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_pic/change_pic.php">
                <strong>Upload Image:</strong> <br><br>
                <input type="file" name="profile-pic" id="profile-pic" />
                <input type="hidden" name="hdn-profile-id" id="hdn-profile-id" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="hdn-x1-axis" id="hdn-x1-axis" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="hdn-y1-axis" id="hdn-y1-axis" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="hdn-x2-axis" value="" id="hdn-x2-axis" />
                <input type="hidden" name="hdn-y2-axis" value="" id="hdn-y2-axis" />
                <input type="hidden" name="hdn-thumb-width" id="hdn-thumb-width" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="hdn-thumb-height" id="hdn-thumb-height" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="" id="action" />
                <input type="hidden" name="image_name" value="" id="image_name" />
                <div id='preview-profile-pic'></div>
                <div id="thumbs" style="padding:5px; width:600p"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" id="save_crop" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div></br>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="profile_pic_modal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h3>Upload Profile Picture</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="cropimage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_and_change.php">
                            <strong>Upload Image:</strong> <br><br>
                            <input type="file" name="profile-pic" id="profile-pic" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="hdn-profile-id" id="hdn-profile-id" value="1" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="hdn-x1-axis" id="hdn-x1-axis" value="" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="hdn-y1-axis" id="hdn-y1-axis" value="" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="hdn-x2-axis" value="" id="hdn-y2-axis" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="hdn-thumb-width" id="hdn-thumb-width" value="" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="hdn-thumb-height" id="hdn-thumb-height" value="" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="" id="action" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="image_name" value="" id="image_name" />

                            <div id='preview-profile-pic'></div>
                            <div id="thumbs" style="padding:5px; width:600p"></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" id="save_crop" class="btn btn-primary" name="save">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </br></br></br></br></br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the function.js where I think the "Uploading..." is coming from:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
/* When click on change profile pic */  
jQuery('#change-profile-pic').on('click', function(e){
    jQuery('#profile_pic_modal').modal({show:true});        
}); 
jQuery('#profile-pic').on('change', function()  { 
    jQuery("#preview-profile-pic").html('');
    jQuery("#preview-profile-pic").html('Uploading....');
    jQuery("#cropimage").ajaxForm(
    {
    target: '#preview-profile-pic',
    success:    function() { 
            jQuery('img#photo').imgAreaSelect({
            aspectRatio: '1:1',
            onSelectEnd: getSizes,
        });
        jQuery('#image_name').val(jQuery('#photo').attr('file-name'));
        }
    }).submit();

});
/* handle functionality when click crop button  */
jQuery('#save_crop').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
params = {
        targetUrl: '/upload_pic/change_pic.php?action=save',
        action: 'save',
        x_axis: jQuery('#hdn-x1-axis').val(),
        y_axis : jQuery('#hdn-y1-axis').val(),
        x2_axis: jQuery('#hdn-x2-axis').val(),
        y2_axis : jQuery('#hdn-y2-axis').val(),
        thumb_width : jQuery('#hdn-thumb-width').val(),
        thumb_height:jQuery('#hdn-thumb-height').val()
    };
    saveCropImage(params);
});
/* Function to get images size */
function getSizes(img, obj){
    var x_axis = obj.x1;
    var x2_axis = obj.x2;
    var y_axis = obj.y1;
    var y2_axis = obj.y2;
    var thumb_width = obj.width;
    var thumb_height = obj.height;
    if(thumb_width > 0) {
        jQuery('#hdn-x1-axis').val(x_axis);
        jQuery('#hdn-y1-axis').val(y_axis);
        jQuery('#hdn-x2-axis').val(x2_axis);
        jQuery('#hdn-y2-axis').val(y2_axis);
        jQuery('#hdn-thumb-width').val(thumb_width);
        jQuery('#hdn-thumb-height').val(thumb_height);
    } else {
        alert("Please select portion..!");
    }
}
/* Function to save crop images */
function saveCropImage(params) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: params['targetUrl'],
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        data: {
            action: params['action'],
            id: jQuery('#hdn-profile-id').val(),
             t: 'ajax',
                                w1:params['thumb_width'],
                                x1:params['x_axis'],
                                h1:params['thumb_height'],
                                y1:params['y_axis'],
                                x2:params['x2_axis'],
                                y2:params['y2_axis'],
                                image_name :jQuery('#image_name').val()
        },
        type: 'Post',
        success: function (response) {
                jQuery('#profile_pic_modal').modal('hide');
                jQuery(".imgareaselect-border1,.imgareaselect-border2,.imgareaselect-border3,.imgareaselect-border4,.imgareaselect-border2,.imgareaselect-outer").css('display', 'none');

                jQuery("#profile_picture").attr('src', response);
                jQuery("#preview-profile-pic").html('');
                jQuery("#profile-pic").val();
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('status Code:' + xhr.status + 'Error Message :' + thrownError);
        }
    });
}
});
```

I have attempted to comment out the line `jQuery("#preview-profile-pic").html('Uploading....');` but that does not seem to remove the "Uploading..." text and the picture still does not upload.

If someone could help me figure out why the module is not working correctly, I would greatly appreciate it. If there is an easier way to get the functionality I am looking for, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

From my analysis, I did ran the code and found lots of more errors but the following are the key issues to address first.

1. Your code uses an assigned header file, as seen [here](https://www.phpzag.com/image-upload-and-crop-in-modal-with-php-and-jquery/) ,that carries all the snippets for CDN jquery files. if you would have opened your console while its 'Uploading...' you would have noticed an error like one in this pic

[image: So from the pic, You have a type error that your Query("#cropimage").ajaxForm is not a function.]
First impression is that no jQuery.form.js  file was found which is responsible for this function. If you go further and confirm that it is correctly loaded, Use this function here to check its loading:

```
 (function() {
var startingTime = new Date().getTime();
// Load the script
var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
script.src = 'dist_files/jquery.form.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

// Poll for jQuery to come into existance
var checkReady = function(callback) {
    if (window.jQuery) {
        callback(jQuery);
    }
    else {
        window.setTimeout(function() { checkReady(callback); }, 20);
    }
};

// Start polling...
checkReady(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var endingTime = new Date().getTime();
        var tookTime = endingTime - startingTime;

        window.alert("jQuery.form is loaded, after " + tookTime + " milliseconds!");
    });
});
```

})();

if you would use this function to check if its correctly loaded, after then, if it loads, your next victim is your jQuery, this is because of compatibility issues, the jQuery.form.js version used requires a jQuery of 1.5.x or higher.

Secondly,you have to check that you don't have any conflict with your imports, if in your project you used a version like
 Assuming you had used jQuery in your other functions before the profile thing came in, which in this case came with its imports.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

then definitely you'll not have jQuery functioning, meaning, jQuery will no work, and also, the same guy needs to call jQuery.form.js, now you see you'll come back to the same error. so harmonize your imports and delete any duplicates in .js imports and also .css files(although there is no css conflict currently but just for your info)

Once you clean the imports(I advise you use CDN if you are developing with good network connection) clear your browser caches and redo the upload with 'inspect element option in your browser' Do this:

- Right click an empty space on browser
- select 'inspect element'
- switch in the inspector to 'Console' and you'll be able to see the errors if any.

your end result should work and get something of this sort:

[image: Notice that the console is clean of errors]